# How do I populate check boxes from Database using PHP/MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with three database tables.

- users
- class
- user_class

I'm making a page so that student can be assigned to classes using a checkbox. How do I get it so that if the value of a student being in a class is currently in the database, the checkbox for that class will already have the student value checked.

```
<?php
$showAllStudents = "SELECT * FROM users";
 mysqli_query($mysqli, $showAllStudents) or die ('Error finding Students');

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $showAllStudents);

echo"<table border='1' cellspacing='10' align='center'>";
echo "<tr><th></th><th>User ID</th><th>User Name</th><th>First Name</th>
<th>Second Name</th></tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='" .$row->userID . "' 
   name='check_box[]' value='" .$row->userID . "' /></td>";
   echo "<td>" .$row->userID . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" .$row->username . "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row->forename . "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row->surname . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

if (isset($_POST['submitClassStudent'])) {
//get ID from header
$classID = $_GET['id'];
//print_r ($_POST);

//for each ticked checkbox convert to a UserID variable
foreach ($_POST['check_box'] as $userID) {
    $editClassStudentQuery = "INSERT INTO `user_class`(userID, classID)
                               VALUES('$userID', '$classID')";
    $insert_row = $mysqli->query($editClassStudentQuery) or die($mysqli->error . __LINE__);
    if ($insert_row) {
        header('Location: classeditor.php');
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $editClassStudentQuery . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: This is a basic HTML question. Lookup the syntax for a checkbox to see how to mark it as checked.

Comment: I think he wants us to get the relations from MySQL...?

Comment: I know how to mark a checkbox as already checked, I am just struggling with how to populate the checkbox if the value currently exists within the database.

Answer (score 0):

To mark a checkbox as already checked you just need to add `checked` as one of its attributes.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="already-checked" checked> Already checked
```

[W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

Answer (score 0):

if the user exists then echo 'checked' in  tag
Example: `echo "<input type ='checkbox'";if(YourConditionHere)echo "checked>";else echo ">";`

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try now